# Combinatorics of signed oriented graphs/skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices

Consider a "complete" [signed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_graph) on $n$ vertices indexed by
$1,2,\dots,n$, that is, a graph in which any two distinct vertices $i$ and $j$ are connected by an oriented edge.
For each pair of vertices $i$ and $j$, write $v_{ij}=1$ or $-1$ depending on whether the connecting edge
goes from $i$ to $j$ or from $j$ to $i$, respectively, and $v_{ii}=0$. The corresponding
[adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $V=(v_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$
is a [skew-symmetric matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) with entries
$\pm1$ only outside the main diagonal. In particular, its determinant is 0 for $n$ odd and nonnegative
for $n$ even; by a simple parity argument it can be shown that $\det(V)$ is odd (hence positive) in the latter case.
On the other hand, $\det(V)$ seems to assume all possible odd positive values restricted only by
[Hadamard's_inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality).

My general question is whether the condition $\det(V)=1$ imposes some known combinatorial structure
in the set of complete signed oriented graphs (or maybe in a reasonable subset of this set).
Some kind of related questions is whether the matrix $V$ in general imposes some interesting
combinatorial structure of the underlying graph (I even do not the answer in the case when $v_{ij}$
depends only on the distance $i-j$, that is, $v_{ij}=\epsilon_{i-j}$).

Comment: This combinatorial structure (a complete graph with an orientation)
is known as a *tournament*. Also, as a skew-symmetric matrix,
$\det(V)$ is a square (the square of the Pfaffian of $V$).

Comment: Robin, I provide the required links which explain that $\det(V)$ is the square of the Pfaffian. I can even compute the Pfaffian as a single determinant of a $(n/2)\times(n/2)$ matrix in the case $v_{ij}=\epsilon_{i-j}$. A tournament is another way to say a complete signed (oriented) graph, but I am looking for a structure of graphs satisfying $\det(V)=1$.

Comment: Wadim, Robin was commenting on your statement that "det(V) seems to assume all possible odd positive values restricted only by Hadamard's_inequality": there is an additional requirement that det(V) be a perfect square (or you should say Pfaffian).

Comment: Victor and Robin, thanks for notifying this mistake. Yes, of course, I meant that only the squares have to be taken in the range.

Comment: Did you try to interpret the determinant as generating function for non-intersecting lattice paths via Stembridge's theorem (Advances in Mathematics 83, Nonintersecting Paths, Pfaffians, and Plane Partitions)?

Comment: Martin, thank you for the tip. No, I didn't. But I'll try to do so today.